# Using type static methods in generic method. C#

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

```
public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component<T>
{
    return (T) components[T.GetMask()];
}
```

In Component< T > GetMask() decleared as static. So why I can't execute this method, compiler even doesn't see any methods, if I use restriction that guarantee at compile time that nothing else then Component< T > and inherited types will't use as T?

I know the way how to implement it through instantiating T type object, but this implementation not suitable for my task.

To make question have an alternative answers, I need get component of base class Component< T > from wich user inherits, from entity in wich all components stores in Dictionary< TypeMask, ComponentBase >. 
Component< T > inherits from ComponentBase. To get component from entity there are GetComponent() methods. If don't use generics methods user will have write the same as written at 4-th line of example below. So, maybe there is alternative way to get components, but i don't see it.

```
Position pos = entity.GetComponent(Position.Mask); //I need that
Position pos = entity.GetComponent<Position>(); //or that

Position pos = (Position)entity.GetComponent(Position.Mask); //but not that
```

I'm sorry for grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the static method over Component instead of T

```
public T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component<T> {
    return (T) components[Component<T>.GetMask()];
}
```

Comment: So obvious that I dont noticed. Thanks a lot.